# AsyncHttpClient doesn't respond in some cases

Tags: java, android

I've got a problem with **AsyncHttpClient**, because it in some cases responds and in some cases not. When I run this function below, I get no data and in **logcat** I can see following Warining:

```
JsonHttpResponseHandler﹕ onSuccess(int, Header[], JSONArray) was not overriden, but callback was received
```

Here is code of my functions:

```
private void getTreningPlan() {
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("userId", user.getUserId());
        invokeWS(params);
    }

    private void invokeWS(RequestParams params) {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("http://" + Constants.address + ":" + Constants.port + "/silownia_java/rest/plan/plansByID", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject obj) {
                Log.i("TAG", "HERE");
                try {

                    TrainingPlan trainingPlan = new TrainingPlan();
                    ArrayList<TrainingDay> trainingDayArrayList = new ArrayList<TrainingDay>();

                    JSONArray trainingDays = obj.getJSONArray("trainingDays");

                    (...............)

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Niepoprawna odpowiedź serwera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                if (statusCode == 404) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "404 - Nie odnaleziono serwera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "500 - Coś poszło nie tak po stronie serwera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), throwable.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, throwable.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I have not idea, why it happens, because I'm using **AsyncHttpClient** in some cases in my project and it always behaves well.
I can add, that my application have connection with my server, and on server side this http responds well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when http response is JSONObject but when response is JSONArray, then it gives this problem. Make sure to return JSONObject if your using

```
 @Override
  public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject obj) {
 }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if returning JSON array then

```
@Override
  public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray jsonArray) {
 }
```